# NetSuite - Auto-Populate Custom Body Fields with Line Item fields

Tags: javascript, field, netsuite, suitescript

I'm new to NetSuite scripting. I'm trying to populate 3 custom body fields in an **Item Fulfillment** form, with the following data: Line Item Name, Line Item Class, and Line Item Count (the total count of line items in the fulfillment form).

For that, I'm using `nlapiGetCurrentLineItemText('item', 'class');` to get the Class of the line item, `nlapiGetCurrentLineItemText('item', 'item');` to get the name, and `nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');` to get the line item count. And `nlapiSetFieldValue` to populate the fields.

I'm setting this script to run on the **Page Init event** (not sure if that's the appropriate event). I'm having two issues:

1. Class and Item Count are populating fine when the Fulfill Sales Order page runs, but the Item name field is not getting populated. Any thoughts on that?
2. When I perform a bulk fulfillment (fulfilling many orders at a time in the Fulfill Orders page), none of the fields would get populated. It's like the script would only run when fulfilling orders manually, but not when it's being done automatically in bulk. Any thoughts on that one?

The second issue is probably the most critical, since having the ability to fulfill orders automatically and get the proper fields populated is necessary when we are fulfilling 100-200 orders in a day.

Hope I explained myself as clearly as possible. Thanks for your help!!

This is the current script:

```
function pageInit() {

{
    var category = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemText('item', 'class');
    var sku = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemText('item', 'item');
    var count = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
    nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_itemcategory', category);
    nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_itemsku', sku);
    nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_skucount', count);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For #1, you're getting the ItemText not the value. I assume that custbody_itemsku is a List/Record field of Item. If that's the case, use:

`var sku = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item');`

For #2, your client script will not be triggered when doing bulk fulfillment. Use user event script instead. You can populate the fields on `beforeSubmit`.

Comment: This worked!
Used the `nlapiGetLineItemValue` instead though.
Load it on the beforeSubmit function at user event.
Thank you very much!